# Apollo useLazyQuery listen on completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo

I am using graphql with Apollo for a signup page.
`onSubmit` I want to send a query to confirm if the username is unique (currently counting users, I know I should check for exists, but not the scope of this question)

I have several problems doing that.
Using `useQuery` sends the Query instantly - I cant choose to send the query on submit.
Using `useLazyQuery` sends the Query delayed on calling `user_count`.
-> Problem: It is neither a promise nor does `onComplete` work (a function that exists in `useQuery` and executes once the query finished)

How does `useLazyQuery` work? It executes the query. The values are accessible through `data_user` which gets updated once the query finishes. `data_user` is initally `undefined`.

As `useLazyQuery` does not return a promise, I decided to create my own promise-like listener.
For what I know the recommended way to do it is a `Proxy`. The problem with that is: Trying to set `target= data_user` throws

```
Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler
```

I could solve it with a `setCallback` function that looks every couple MS for a change, but that feels dirty.

```js
export default function Signup() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([])
    const [user_count, {loading, data: data_user}] = useLazyQuery(USER_COUNT);

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const proxy = new Proxy(data_user, {
            set: function (target, prop, value) {
                if (prop === 'userCount') {
                    console.log("Query finished")
                    const user_exists = data_user.userCount !== 0;
                    console.log(`User exists: ${user_exists}`)
                }
            }
        })

        user_count({
            variables: {
                name: state.value
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to workaround this problem by using `useApolloClient` directly:

````js
const client = useApolloClient();

const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        client
            .query({
                query: USER_COUNT,
                variables: {
                    name: state.value
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                const user_exists = response.data.userCount !== 0;
                console.log(`User already exists: ${user_exists}`)
            });
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Window Abort controller to cancel the request

> Learn more here:
> https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/aborting-queries-and-mutations-in-react-apollo

at the end of article check the complete example hope it will help you out

Comment: I didnt want to cancel a request, I want something to happen (Either create an account or show an error) after the request has finished. Found a workaround now tho.